# pipe output into a delete command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, clearcase

i am trying to delete files created by this command cleartool ls -r -view_only

The output looks like .\noc\shared\dpcversioninfo.rc.keep

I want to pipe this into a del command like 
cleartool ls -r -view_only|del /q and get bad syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`del` command does not read data from stdin. You will need to retrieve the output of the `cleartool` command and use it as argument to `del`

The way to do it in windows is to use a `for /f` command. It can execute a command and iterate over its output lines, executing the code after the `do` clause for each of them, with the contents of the line stored in the indicated replaceable parameter (the `for` *variable*)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cleartool ls -r -view_only') do echo del /q "%%a"
```

This will echo to console the `del` commands. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command.